# Error handling user input

Tags: ms-access

Hi i am using an access form which asks the user to enter a number. I am trying to handle errors which include; 1. If value entered = null, 2. If the value entered is not an integer. i have tried with my code below but still get an "type mismatch error"

```
 Dim refNum As Integer


 refNum = InputBox("Please enter the Reference Number")

 If IsNumeric(refNum) Then

 MsgBox ("ok")

 ElseIf refNum = Null Then

 MsgBox (" Field is empty , enter a number")

 Else


 MsgBox (" Please enter a number")


End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these 2 lines ...

```vb
Dim refNum As Integer
refNum = InputBox("Please enter the Reference Number")
```

If the user types any of the following into the `InputBox`, the code will throw a type mismatch error.

- letters, eg "abc"
- a number larger than 32767
- nothing

The reason for that is because it attempts to store the `InputBox` value to a variable, `refNum`, which was declared as `Integer`.  The user could however enter a floating point number, and the assignment to `refNum` will discard the decimal places.  For example, if the user enters 1.2, the value of `refNum` will be 1.

An `InputBox` offers limited direct control of the users' inputs.  Since you're doing this from a form, consider an unbound textbox, `txtRefNum`, to collect the value from the user.  Check the value In the text box's before update event,  display your message for unacceptable values and `Cancel` the update.

In a comment, you indicated you want *"an error handler to trap the mismatch error when assigning to refNum, notify the user, and throw up the InputBox again."*  In that case, this code does what you want.

```vb
    Dim refNum As Integer
    Dim strMsg As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    refNum = InputBox("Please enter the Reference Number")
    MsgBox "ok"

ExitHere:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case 13 ' type mismatch
        MsgBox "Reference NUMBER!"
        Resume ' present InputBox again
    Case Else
        strMsg = "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ")"
        MsgBox strMsg
        GoTo ExitHere
    End Select
```

Comment: Ok so there is no error handling available for Input Box if the user does not enter a integer ?

Comment: No.  You could add an error handler to trap the mismatch error when assigning to `refNum`, notify the user, and throw up the `InputBox` again.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks For your code , i tried it but i still get a type mis match error

Comment: Sorry HansUp it does work , just 1 more thing how can i edited it so the user can press cancel on the dialog box and close the dialog box ?

Comment: An `InputBox` *always* returns a string.  If the user clicks OK without entering a value or clicks Cancel, the `Inputbox` returns an empty string ... there's no way to tell which was clicked.  If you must use an `InputBox` for this, instruct the users to enter some "magic" number (perhaps -1?) to signal they've decided not to enter a Reference Number.  Your code would have to check whether the `recNum` value is equal to the magic number and abort.

Answer (score 0):

Your refNum variable needs to be a variant or a string.  When you assign your InputBox to refNum as an integer your InputBox expects only integer values and so breaks before getting to your if statement.

If you use a string you would also need to change your elseif.

```
ElseIf refNum = Null Or refNum = "" Then
```

Comment: I declared it as an integer because i only want the user to enter a number only, enter a string value or enter a null value